# If choosing from "ends", shouldn't it be "which end"?

Tags: grammar

> Aristotle did not think that all human beings should be allowed to engage in political activity: in his system, women, slaves, and foreigners were explicitly excluded from the right to rule themselves and others. Nevertheless, his basic idea that politics is a unique collective activity that is directed at certain common goals and ends still resonates today. **But which ends?** Many thinkers and political figures since the ancient world have developed different ideas about the goals that politics can or should achieve. This approach is known as political moralism.

If choosing from "ends", shouldn't it be "which end"?

Comment: Why should it? Why should we choose only one goal or end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you may want to choose several different "ends"

"Ends" in this context means goals, and a politician will have many goals, and many "ends".